# Paraview x3d file rendering in Blender

Tags: animation, 3d-view

I have a simulation with some nice bubbles floating in the water. I am very new to the Blender community and by reading about it a bit (and also performing some tutorials) tried to render my simulation result first on paraview and then render it in Blender.

I have a left and right wall and then the bubbles floating around in the fluid(the space between the walls). The red and the blue wakes are the volmetric rendering of the temperature in those cells with the mid range blanked out. What that means is my left wall is cold and right wall is hot. I selectively set some the mid range as transparent and I am only interested in the boundary layers at the walls.

When I export the x3d file and import it in Blender (say for one snapshot) I do get the walls and the bubbles but I dont get the volumetric rendering of the temperature field. My paraview file and blender files after import looks like this

[image]

1. How do I render the temperature field (the field that appears colored in the paraview version) ?
   The view always appears to be rotated in the blender, i guess the orientation of axis in paraview and blender is different.
2. How do i import more such snapshots to create a movie out of this ?

PS: [Link to download the X3D file hosted on pcloud](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ8ues7ZIYqynecn7KFYl6UDMEuzsyg5Txp7)

Comment: If you upload a couple of frames of data, it will help courting out how to animate.

Comment: @EdTate sure i will try that. Any idea on te rendering of volumetric temperature field.